# how to parse a text file in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have a text file that I want to parse out into several text files.  The file is too large to open in Excel.  So, my best guess is to do this somehow in SSIS.  (Really, because that's all I know how to do at the moment.)  I could do it manually in Notepad++, but I need an automated solution moving forward.

The source text file has no headers, has records with various numbers of columns, all similar records are grouped together, and the file is pipe-delimited.

Here is a sample text file that I want to parse:

```
A|stuff CRLF
A|more_stuff CRLF
B|stuff|more_text CRLF
B|more_stuff|yet_more_text CRLF
```

(The CRLFs are end-of-row delimiters.  As you can see, the number of columns for 'A' records is different than for 'B' records.)

I want to put all records with the same value in the first column into separate text files.  That is, I want to put all 'A' records into one text file, and I want to put all 'B' records into another text file.  I don't want to have to go through a SQL table.  Is this possible in SSIS?  If so, how do I do so?  If not, what tool is best for this situation?

Comment: You could use SSIS but you could also stick needles in your eyes. When I need to parse CSV files I use C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you add a data flow task to your package you can use a conditional split.  In the conditional split  you'll need to label what A and B are using an expression of some sort.  In your case it would be something like this:  Output Name = A, Condition would be  [Name of Column] == "A".  Do the same thing for B too and then when you connect the output arrows to your flat file destinations you can choose which output to put with which text file.

Comment: Thats fine but SSIS doesn't handle ragged right (variable columns) very well. SSIS is a bit over the top for this purpose

Comment: Would you suggest C# instead?

Answer (score 0):

It Can be possible with Flatfilesource ,Derivedcolumns,ConditionalSplit transformation. Represent each row having single column. for that give column delimiter which doesn't have in the input file (eg. ^).

[image: FlatFileSource]

[image: DerivedColumns]z.png

[image: ConditionalSplit]

[image: DataFlow task]